# Finding the average of multiple coordinate paths

Tags: coordinate-systems, average

I'm not entirely sure what methodology I should use to go about this.

I've got multiple sets of flight data containing latitude, longitude, and altitude at different times for those points. What I want to do is find the average path a given flight takes in that three-dimensional space.

Is there any algorithm that can help with determining this? I'm currently using python for computation, but can try a different language such as R if you happen to know of some existing functionality. Pure math is fine too, of course.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but why not just average the quantities (latitude, longitude, altitude) for each time and use that?

Comment: The times may not match up. For example, the first point on one flight may be recorded twenty seconds before the second on one flight, while it may be recorded only 18 seconds before on the next. The two flights may have a different number of total points, or even on two very similar flight paths, the points may all be recorded half a recording period ahead of the first. (Though, I'm not sure if that last one would be a real issue.)

Comment: is the recording period always the same?

Comment: No, there's some pretty wide variation in how frequently the points are recorded. While I'm not sure exactly how much it can vary, looking over some of it by eye shows that sometimes there's less than a second between points, but sometimes as many as ten seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose for altitude, you have a set of data: $A_1(a_1,t_1)...A_n(a_n,t_n)$ where $a_n$ is the altitude at time instant $t_n$.

Since the recording frequency is highly irregular(as you stated in your comment), I suggest you to interpolate the data. Polynomial interpolation, spline interpolation and Gaussian process are all good candidates. In addition, I believe a computer version of these algorithms(in the language you are using) should be very common and open-sourced, as long as you don’t demand too much.

After interpolation, you will have a function $A(t)$. If you want the average of three flight’s altitudes, you can consider: $$A_{average}(t)=\frac{A_A(t)+A_B(t)+A_C(t)}{3}$$

Same for other dimensions.

Comment: I don't think he has a global time.

Comment: I do actually have a global time. Each entry comes with an epoch time. I'll give this a try.

Comment: Oh, nice. This makes things easier.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a good average.

Take two paths $A=[(x_a,t_a),...,(x_b,t_b)]$ and $B=[(y_{\alpha},t_{\alpha}),...,(y_{\beta},t_{\beta})]$. Suppose they have a shift in real time by $\tau$. 
So define $t_{\alpha}=t_a+\tau$

The two paths may have different many points that taken at different recording periods. We fill in the gaps by inter- and extrapolating your data.

$A'=[(x'_0,t'_0),(x'_1,t'_1),...,(x'_n,t'_n)]$ and $B'=[(y'_0,t'_{0}+\tau),(y'_1,t'_{t_1}+\tau),...,(y'_n,t'_{n}+\tau)]$

Now you have two paths that have $n+1$ many points.

If the pilot tried to fly on an ideal path (and is a good pilot) for all the paths then the following makes sense:

You look at the sum of the differences of the two paths and minimize it by changing $\tau$. I.e. find $$\min\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}x'_k-y'_k \right). $$

Every time you change $\tau$ the path $B$ shifts in time. This means the differences will change. Once you find the ideal shift $\tau_0$, you keep that shift for $B$.

Take a third path $C=[(z_{\gamma},t_{\gamma}),...,(z_{\delta},t_{\delta})]$ and fill in the gaps with $A$ and $B$. Then you obtain $C'=[(z'_0,t'_0+\tau),(z'_1,t'_1+\tau),...,(z'_m,t'_m+\tau)]$. You have to extend $A, B$ from $n+1$ to $m+1$ points too. Finally you minimize the sum again
$$\min\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}x'_k-y'_k -z'_k\right), $$ for different $\tau$. Find the ideal shift $\tau_1$ and repeat with the rest of the paths. Then all your paths will have equally many points with equal time steps. Now take the average of all the paths $A',B'C',...$.